# jQuery Mobile: Fixed side-bar to go with fixed header

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, css-position

I'd like to have a vertical split view bar at the left of the page which stays fixed like the `data-position="fixed"` header bar I have is.

Like in [this example](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html) (edit: this link now broken) but with the list at the left also fixed, tagging along with the header.

I thought about trying to insert it into the header for it to "inherit" the fixed positioning. Not sure if that would work.

Here are the contents of my stylesheet.

```
.content-right {
    float: right;
    width: 75%;
}
.content-left {
    width: 23%; /* Not 25%: I am not using padding */
}
```

The `.content-right` div comes first in the HTML.

What I would also like is for this bar to gracefully slide up if the fixed header gets hidden (via a click) but this is not nearly as important (I can just force the click-hide off for now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with uses a fixed div for the left side and the right side is the actual "page" which scrolls naturally.

Since my left div stretches off the page, on desktop browsers the scrollbar also goes off the page. That needs to be dealt with. However, on iOS5, using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`  the fixed div scrolling functions *perfectly*!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing out of the box.

You could use my [multiview plugin](https://github.com/frequent/multiview), which is in the works. I'm finishing the navigation and panel history right now. Plus fixing everything for tablet/smartphone view. If you don't mind the bugs still in there for now it would be ready to use (please post issues on Github).

Here is one sample page I'm working currently testing with:  [sample-overthrow](http://www.stokkers.mobi/jqm/multiview/sample-over.html)

This view locks the screen and scrolls each panel separately using [overthrow](https://github.com/filamentgroup/Overthrow/). Nothing to configure except add *data-scrollmode="overthrow"* to the wrapper page. Check the HTML to see how its set up. Also beware, this is my first attempt at integrating Overthrow and it's not very smooth yet.

in which the whole page scrolls like a regular JQM page. This is the default behavior.

You can use 1/2/3 panels side by side (need to label them "menu", "mid" and "main", I'm removing "fullwidth" from the code - used in previous versions), so if you only want a "navbar/sidebar" on the side, just use a menu with ... 50px width and put your toolbar in there. The main panel should scale automatically to fill the screen. I also started on a yield-mode which allows to slide in/out the toolbar. Haven't got around to finishing this yet.

Comment: Do you have a link where we can see it in action?

Comment: ups. I liked to the Git Repo. Try clicking "sample-overthrow" and "sample-fixed" again now